# Why is TinyMCE not converting my html to their wysiwyg format?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, tinymce

I'm using codeigniter and have an edit page, on this page I have an TinyMCE editor. This is how I load the javascript files:

```
<script src='<?php echo site_url('js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js'); ?>'></script>

<script>
tinymce.init({
selector: '.tinymce'
});
</script>
```

This works great when adding code, and it shows up as < p > test < / p > (without spaces).

When I edit a page however, the p-tags or other tags aren't converted to the wysiwyg, they just show up as p-tags (see picture below).

[image: p-tags showing up in the wysiwyg editor]

[screenshot of the source view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErBgM.png)

this is how I'm getting the data in the textarea:

```
<?php echo form_textarea('body', set_value('body', $page->body), 'class="form-control tinymce" placeholder="Inhoud"'); ?>
```

the set_value just puts the actual content inside the value of the input.

Comment: Tools > Source Code  That's what you need ? It's not clear what you want.

Comment: How do you pull content back from the database to edit?  Are you placing it directly in a `<textarea>`?  Using `setContent()`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Codeiginter 3, the "set_value()" function accepts a third parameter, html escape. Details here: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=set_value#set_value

So you should use:

```
<?php echo form_textarea('body', set_value('body', $page->body, false), 'class="form-control tinymce" placeholder="Inhoud"'); ?>
```

I'm using the following tinymce javascript setting also: `format: 'raw'`

I had the same problem and this solution works.

Next time you should also search on the codeigniter forum - https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-1035.html

Answer (score 0):

When You write any thing in editor it's already wrapped with tags. When you want to write html in editor,

If that sourc code is disable you can make it enable using following code snippet. [(More)](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/code/)

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: "code",
  toolbar: "code",
  menubar: "tools"
});
```

There is one option at Tools > Source Code > Write your HTML code there.

[image]

Comment: That source code is disabled, that's the weird thing. It just keeps adding a p tag around the p tags already there. So when I save the page again it's like this:< p > < p > test < / p > < p > test < / p>< / p > 

Which I'm sure you can understand is a bit problematic :P

Comment: I have edited my answer how you can enable 'source code' option.
You are also getting extra <p> tag that means you are not converting value in proper format. Can you provide some more details on how you get the value of text area.  and how you are rendering on the page.

Comment: I provided a screenshot of the source view at my original question

Comment: Doesn't make sense why you are using p tag inside the text area. If you want to write html than use source code screen. And inside text area don't use html tag.

Comment: This is what is retrieved from the database, I didn't write this in here myself. TinyMCE adds p tags around the text the first time and when I'm trying to edit the page it reads the data back from the database but it's not interperted right by TinyMCE

Answer (score 0):

if you use {{ $post->body }} then same database output display in html

This is working -> {!! $post->body !!}